# Conditionally mapping two different arrays into a React component depending on boolean value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently have an array called `options` which is mapped into a React component like so:

```
{options.map((option) => (
   <Component key={option.code}></Component>
))}
```

However, I am trying to expand my component so that if a boolean value: `shouldCount` is true, then the `optionsWithCount` array is passed to the component instead of the `options` array. The component above has a lot more props etc than shown so I'd like to avoid just repeating the component with all of its props if possible.

Can anyone suggest a possible way of going about this?

Comment: What about saving the array you want before rendering, then using the same map function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would using a utils function `getOptions()` work? It would take in the `shouldCount` flag as input and return the desired array. Example:

```
{ 
  getOptions(shouldCount).map((option) => (
    <Component key={option.code}></Component>
  ));
}

const getOptions = (shouldCount) => {
  return shouldCount ? optionsWithCount : options;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update the options variable conditionally so you don't have to rewrite the same code again.

Make options a state;

```
const [options, setOptions] = useState([])
```

And use `useEffect` to update it;

```
useEffect(()=>{
    if(shouldCount) setOptions([1,2,3,4,5])
    else setOptions([5,6,7,8,9])
}, [shouldCount])
```

So that way, when shouldCount changed it will trigger useEffect and change optinos values.